# SQL group by, not sure what it's called

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

First off, I'm sure the answer for this is here somewhere but I just don't know what this particular problem is called to search for it.

I have a log table like this:

```
id | key | value | timestamp
=====================================
1  | a   | apple | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0001
2  | b   | bat   | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0002
3  | a   | apple | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0003
4  | b   | bat   | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0004
5  | a   | apple | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0005
6  | b   | bat   | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0006
```

I want to do a query like:

select key, value, timestamp from log group by key order by timestamp desc

I would like the query to return the follow:

```
id | key | value | timestamp
=====================================
5  | a   | apple | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0005
6  | b   | bat   | 2013-02-05 01:01:01.0006
```

But it tells me I'm supposed to put timestamp in the group by which defeats the purpose. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL btw.

Comment: could you show what you'd like to see as output, your question is not entirely clear to me

Comment: So what timestamp do you want returned. Look at key A: d you want .0001, .0003 or .0005?, you need to perform an aggregrate on timestamp then something like min, max, avg

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Because there are multiple distinct `timestamp`s per `key` group by is looking to group the set before ordering/filtering (it's usually used with aggregates). If you'd like all timestamps then you need to `ORDER BY key ASC timestamp ASC`. If you'd just like the min/max (aggregate functions) `timestamp` of each key, then one of the extant answers will work.

Comment: yes of course. I would like to see the last key value that was updated. So in this case id 5 and 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original post requested to see id field, and other answers seem to have ignored this and also assumed that key and value have 1:1 mapping (not a silly assumption).

To get the rows from log with the latest timestamp for each key:

```
with latestLog as (
    select  key, max(timestamp) latestTimestamp
    from    logTable
    group by key)
select  l.*
from    log l join latestLog ll on l.key = ll.key and l.timestamp = ll.latestTimestamp
```

Comment: This one worked! I was getting rows with different values with the other queries. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

because you are not using `Aggregate` function on atleast some fields, try

```
SELECT key, value, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
FROM   log 
GROUP  BY key, value
ORDER  BY max_timestamp DESC
```

- [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html)
- [Aggregate Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-agg.html)

Comment: doesn't the order by have to be maxed as well?

Comment: @xQbert I used the alias already on my edited answer. `:D` but using `timestamp` will also do.

Comment: That doesn't work actually. if there are different values for 'value' it will display them all

Comment: much better if you can give samplerecords with desired result. I could not really imagine how your records look like

Comment: normally that's true because you have grouped them by key and value

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for last timestamp? Something like:

```
select
    key, 
    value, 
    max(timestamp) t
from 
    log 
group by 
    key,
    value
order by 
    t desc
```